# Adding google-play-services to android dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, google-play-services

I want to have an activity in my application that contains a barcode scanner and for that I need to be able to use BarcodeDetector. To be able to use this I need to implement the dependecy 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'', but when I do this I get the following error message:

[image]

I do not know how to solve this error, my 'build.gradle (Module: app)' looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myname.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And my 'build.gradle (Project: MyProject)' looks like this:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try to add `google()` in your `allprojects` entry, in your Project's gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the libraries that you're including are referencing different versions of some other libraries. That's the problem behind the scenes.

In your example, you're including the whole bundle of play services. According to what you've said, it looks like you might only need the "vision" package. Please, try with following configuration:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
```

These are the changes:

- "+" sign was removed in some libraries by providing an specific version number (the last stable available version today)
- instead of using the whole bundled version of Play Services, I only added play-services-vision, that should be enough. If you also need other package, you can find the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

EDIT: 
You will also need to add `google()` in your Project's gradle to get access to latest libraries, like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm it tells me 'failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'. I installed the repository but the message still shows up

Comment: I've just edited my answer with the solution for that ;)

Comment: it works! instead of adding 'google()' I added maven, but thanks a lot for your help :)